# Problem in reloading page(table) after deleting record from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET CORE MVC application with a table listing some clients (CRUD) and I can delete users when I click in delete.

The problem that i'm trying to resolve is when I refresh the page after delete the records from the listing the listing still show the deleted record when in the database the record is deleted and if I reload (F5) the page manually the record disappear.

I already try the location.reload(), windows.location.reload() and nothing... I can saw that page is reloading but the record don't disappear.

My code is above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function toggleChecked(status) {
            $("#checkboxes input").each(function () {

                // Set the checked status of each to match the
                // checked status of the check all checkbox:
                $(this).prop("checked", status);
            });
        }

        function Delete(id) {
            var example_table = $("#example1")
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
            if (r == true) {

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Clients")',
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == true) {
                            example_table.ajax.reload(); // -->> The problem is in this line!
                            location.reload(); // -->> The problem is in this line!
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("There is a problem, Try Later!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }



        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Set the default value of the global checkbox to true:
            $("#checkall").prop('checked', false);

            // Attach the call to toggleChecked to the
            // click event of the global checkbox:
            $("#checkall").click(function () {
                var status = $("#checkall").prop('checked');
                toggleChecked(status);
            });
        });


    </script>
```

The back-end Delete:

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                Clients client = db.Clients.Where(s => s.Id == id).First();
                db.Clients.Remove(client );
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

I want that the deleted record disappear in real time without have to refresh the page manually. If you can help me I appreciate.

Comment: try location.reload(true)

Comment: @SouXin I already tried but it does not work too.

Comment: show the back-end for Delete

Comment: @SouXin question updated with the deleted.

Comment: Have you tried Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) on server side? or window.location.href= window.location for client side

Comment: just try to find the row index of the table with js and the remove that row from table or set display to none

Answer (score 0):

If the delete is sucessful you could manually remove that item from the list in the sucess of the ajax call. 
However with the reload, does the reload of the page call the database and get a list of data? If this is not triggered from the reload then it wont be updating the list. If it is then my only suggestion would be that cookies may be storing the list?

Comment: I don't think that can be cookies and i'm calling the database in server side.The strangest thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work ... Sometimes the records are deleted in real time others I have to refresh manually and if i try do delete a record that was already deleted in db but the listing still shows the code go to the error side in the ajax and shows: `"There is a problem, Try Later!"`

Answer (score 0):

For Server side refresh you can use `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`

For Client side refresh you can use `window.location.href= window.location`

Or document.location.reload() instead of location.reload()

Comment: window.location.href= window.location doesn't work.

Comment: how about adding Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) to your server side,,,And you said you used location.reaload() but have you tried document.location.reload() instead?

Comment: document.location.reload()  doesn't work too and how I can continue to use the return true (I need to use the ajax in client side) in the delete with the Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)?

Comment: console.log(result) see what are you getting back. maybe the result coming back is not true meaning the it will not pass your if statement

Comment: strange, if I pass the `example_table.ajax.reload();` and the `window.location.reload();` it will not pass in the if (in the true or false). If I only pass, for example, the `alert("test");` it will enter in the if and shows the alert when I click delete in the row.

Comment: try calling another function and reload the page in that function. like if (result == true) { refreshpage() } then in refreshpage function reload the page.

Comment: I found the problem! The problem is on the first delete when the page first open. When the page open for the first time and I click delete I saw the exact same rows but in the db the row was deleted, then if I manually refresh the page the next ones will work with no problem. The problem is in the first reload of the page after the first delete...

Comment: @tgoncalves3 Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? It is difficult to understand your issue by first time, second time.

Comment: @TaoZhou I don't have any demo. I will try to explain better The 1st time that I open the webpage the call don't enter in the if on the ajax call: `success: function (result) {
                        if (result == true) {...}}` basically it does nothing but it deletes the records from the db so it goes to the server side but the `public ActionResult Index()` in this case is only called once before the delete. But if I refresh the page manually for 2 times for example it will works perfectly, it call the alert on success and the `public ActionResult Index()` is called after the delete.